# How does the semantic web actually work?

Tags: semantic-web, linked-data

I know that in the web you have lots an lots of pages linked to one another and you can go from page to page and so on.

How does the semantic web work? I understand that it uses the concept of Linked Data, where data is identified and linked by URIs or IRIs and not the web pages them self. But I don't understand how the data is linked across the web when all of the data is stored in local triplestores and are linked internally in the triplestores. Are browsers capable to go from triplestore to triplestore behind the scenes and get back all kinds of data? Or how is the data actually linked? Is there a mechanism to go from data to data all across the web and use the meaning of data in real life situations, or a tool that does something like this?

Also anybody can create ontologies and define and describe anything in all kinds of different ways. Won't this lead to a big mess of data?

So, main question:

How does the semantic web and liked data actually work?

Comment: You might be interested in this book: "Semantic Web for the working ontologist" http://workingontologist.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tricky and multifaceted question.

### First I'll answer some of you questions.

> But I don't understand how the data is linked across the web when all of the data is stored in local triplestores and are linked internally in the triplestores

First of all, it is important to realize that triplestores are not a necessity. You could have SQL servers and [D2RQ](http://d2rq.org/)/[R2RML](http://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/) mapping on top to translate queries dynamically. Or plain RDF files. Or simple JSON documents in MongoDB, etc, which you extend by [adding a JSON-LD `@context`](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#interpreting-json-as-json-ld).

What is important, is that you serve data in one of the RDF formats such as turtle or JSON-LD

> Are browsers capable to go from triplestore to triplestore behind the scenes and get back all kinds of data?

See, they don't have to because, as you mention, URIs are used so that a browser (not necessarily a web browser) can download the data. And of course these URI are URLs and are [dereferenceable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereferenceable_Uniform_Resource_Identifier). Otherwise they are just identifiers.

> Or how is the data actually linked?

It is linked simply by reusing identifiers for objects and properties. That's why URI (IRI) is used, so that the identifiers are globally unique and created privately within a domain. Of course there is a risk of being mischievous by creating URIs is someone else's domain. It's a separate topic though.

> Is there a mechanism to go from data to data all across the web and use the meaning of data in real life situations, or a tool that does something like this?

One simple mechanism is to simply crawl RDF data and download to a local store. Simple occurrence of matching identifiers will combine the data into larger dataset with less mapping effort required. That is of course the theory because you risk data can be corrupt, incorrect or duplicated so you need some curation.  Technology exists to help you do that and it's not something you wouldn't experience is traditional data warehousing. Search engines harvest semantic markup from HTML pages (RFDa/Microdata) is similar manner.

Another option is to use [federated queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/). SPARQL has the ability to automatically download RDF data and perform queries over it in memory.

Last but not least, there are federated queries using [Triple Pattern Fragments](http://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2015/06/09/federated-sparql-queries-in-your-browser/)

### Now about *Semantic Web*

As I wrote, the question is not that simple. You mostly ask about ***Linked Data***. There is more to Semantic Web than that:

- ontologies/taxonomies
- inferencing
- rules
- semantic/faceted search

I hope I answered your question to some extent.